# How to call a user javascript from a firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, xpcom

I am very new to writing plugins for firefox. I am writing a plugin to intercept a URL protocol (I got it here: http://www.nexgenmedia.net/docs/protocol/) inside the plugin and then call some user loaded Jscript functions to pass data.

My question is, How can i call a user script or a greasemonkey script from within a firefox plugin when the plugin is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally a very bad idea to run arbitrary code from an extension. The extension code is executed in privileged mode with access to `XPCOM` (and thus the whole system).
If you really DO want to execute external JS, the best way is `Components.utils.Sandbox` I suppose. Other options are `nsISubscriptLoader` or `Components.utils.import`.
Also, afaik such extensions won't pass security check at [Mozilla Addons](http://addons.mozilla.org) and won't be accepted there as a result.